# Cantor-Lebesgue function and an increasing function are equal almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure

Denote by $\varphi$ the cantor-lebesgue function and suppose $f$ is a certain increasing function defined on [0,1] and such that $f(x)=\varphi (x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]-C$ where $C$ is the cantor set. Prove that $f(x)=\varphi(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.
Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $x \in C$, we have
$$ \sup\{f(y) : y \le x, \ y \in [0,1]-C\} = \sup\{\varphi(y) : y \le x,\  y \in [0,1]-C\} $$
and
$$ \inf\{f(y) : y \ge x, \ y \in [0,1]-C\} = \inf\{\varphi(y) : y \ge x, \ y \in [0,1]-C\} $$
Now determine that
$$ \sup\{\varphi(y) : y \le x,\  y \in [0,1]-C\} = \inf\{\varphi(y) : y \ge x,\  y \in [0,1]-C\} = \varphi(x)$$
and you will be done.

Comment: Thanks. The proof is clear and easy to understand . Thanks again

Comment: Hi. What is mean the 'determine' exactly? I can't understand why the last sentence clarify the proof.

Comment: @himath I was giving hints on the direction of a possible proof, not every detail.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thanks for answer. I've thought a lot about it, but I can't figure it out. Please give me more detail.

Comment: The 'determine' part follows because $\varphi$ is continuous.  Now substitute the first equalities into the second inequalities.  You will have sandwiched the value of $f(x)$.

Comment: I am a little confused as how this shows $f(x)=\phi(x)$ on $[0,1]$. Wouldn't this just imply they're equal on $[0,1]-C$ which we already knew by assumption?

Comment: @joseph The infs and sups are defined for all $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So should the statement at the top be "For each $x\in[0,1]$" rather than "For each $x\in\mathbf{C}$"?

Comment: It makes no difference, because we already know the two functions agree on the complement of $C$.

Comment: ah yes by assumption we have that! Thank you again for clarifying

Comment: So why do some claim to statement is not true for 0 and 1? As the first answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true as stated. A counterexample is 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \phi(x) \quad &x\in [0,1) \\ 10 & x=1\end{cases}
$$

The correct statement is that $f=\phi$ on $(0, 1)$, which is a special case of the following claim.

**Claim**. If $f, \phi:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ are increasing, $\phi$ is continuous, and $f=\phi$ on a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $f=\phi$ on $(a,b)$.

*Proof*. Suppose that $f(c)> \phi(c)$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. Let $\epsilon=f(c)-\phi(c)$. Since $\phi$ is continuous, there is $\delta>0$ such that $\phi(x)<\phi(c)+\epsilon$ whenever $c<x<c+\delta$. On the other hand, $f(x)\ge f(c) = \phi(c)+\epsilon$, hence $f(x)> \phi(x)$ for all $x\in (c, c+\delta)$. This contradicts the assumption.

The case $f(c)<\phi(c)$ is treated similarly, considering a left neighborhood of $c$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Hi. I know that $\phi(1)=1$. So, from the hypothesis, it have to be that $f(1)=1$. Am I misunderstanding? Thanks!